# What do I not understand about memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, singly-linked-list

For a class I am taking, we are implementing our own singly-linked list in c++ so that we can better understand how the data structure functions. Currently, I have completed the code, which passes all test cases, but running valgrind I find that I still have memory leaks.

I've implemented code that should delete each Node object whenever it is removed from the list, but apparently I have done something wrong. **What do I not understand about memory management that I am missing?**

My code passes some basic testing with no memory leaks, but when using more rigorous test cases provided by my professor, valgrind exhibits major memory leak problems.

Here is my Linked List Class:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList: public LinkedListInterface<T> {

    private:

        struct Node {
            Node(T val) {
                value = val;
                next = NULL;
            }
            T value;
            Node *next;
        };

        Node *head;

    public:

    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;

    }

    ~LinkedList() {

    }

    void insertHead(T value) {
        cout << "In insertHead function" << endl;
        Node *newNode = new Node(value);
        if(head == NULL){
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    //don't allow duplicate values in the list. Implement later.
    void insertTail(T value) {
        cout << "In insertTail function" << endl;
        Node *newNode = new Node(value);

        if(head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            //find last node
            Node *fakeIterator = head;
            //while what fake iterator is pointing to is not NULL then make it point to the next pointer.
            while (fakeIterator->next != NULL) {
                fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
            }
            //set that node's next pointer to newNode
            fakeIterator->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void insertAfter(T value, T insertionNode) {
        cout << "In insertAfter function" << endl;
        Node *fakeIterator = head;

        while(fakeIterator != NULL) {
            if (fakeIterator->value == insertionNode) {
                Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                newNode->next = fakeIterator->next;
                fakeIterator->next = newNode;
                break;
            }
            fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
        }
    }

    string toString() {
        cout << "In toString function" << endl;
        stringstream ss;
        Node *fakeIterator = head;
        while (fakeIterator != NULL) {
            if (fakeIterator->next == NULL)
                ss << fakeIterator->value;
            else
                ss << fakeIterator->value << ", ";

            fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
        }

        return ss.str();
    }

    void remove(T value) {
        cout << "In remove function" << endl;
        if (head != NULL) {
            Node *fakeIterator = head;
            if(head->value == value) {
                Node *nodeToDelete = head;//new Node(value);
                // nodeToDelete = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete nodeToDelete;
            }
            else {
                while(fakeIterator->next != NULL) {
                    //if the value of the node after this one equals the value
                    if ( (fakeIterator->next)->value == value) {
                        //make a temp node to store the node being destroyed
                        Node *nodeToDelete = fakeIterator->next;
                        //change "next" to point to the item after the one being deleted
                        fakeIterator->next = fakeIterator->next->next;
                        //delete the node
                        delete nodeToDelete;
                        break;
                    }
                    fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        cout << "In clear function" << endl;
        while (head != NULL) {
            remove(head->value);
        }
    }

    T at(int index) {
        cout << "In at function" << endl;
        Node *fakeIterator = head;
        if (head == NULL) {
            throw out_of_range("list is empty");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < index ; i++) {
            cout << "2" << endl;
            if (fakeIterator->next == NULL) {
                cout << "3" << endl;
                throw out_of_range("index does not exist");
                break;
            }
            fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
            cout << "4" << endl;
        }

        return fakeIterator->value;
    }

    int size() {
        cout << "In size function" << endl;
        int sizeOfList = 0;
        Node *fakeIterator = head;
        while (fakeIterator != NULL) {
            if (fakeIterator->next == NULL)
                return sizeOfList;
            else
                sizeOfList++;

            fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
        }
    }

};
```

Here is the valgrind output:

```
==14052== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==14052==    at 0x57BFFE0: __read_nocancel (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==14052==    by 0x574CB83: _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==14052==    by 0x574DD51: _IO_default_uflow (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==14052==    by 0x5748729: getchar (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==14052==    by 0x4024C1: main (main.cpp:88)
==14052== 
==14052== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14052==     in use at exit: 16,468 bytes in 696 blocks
==14052==   total heap usage: 2,924 allocs, 2,228 frees, 523,457 bytes allocated
==14052== 
==14052== 96 (16 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 18
==14052==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==14052==    by 0x40442F: LinkedList<int>::insertHead(int) (LinkedList.h:58)
==14052==    by 0x4034A0: void parse_instruction<int>(std::string, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, LinkedList<int>*) (main.cpp:101)
==14052==    by 0x4023AC: main (main.cpp:67)
==14052== 
==14052== 585 (16 direct, 569 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 15 of 18
==14052==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==14052==    by 0x403BEB: LinkedList<std::string>::insertHead(std::string) (LinkedList.h:58)
==14052==    by 0x402C84: void parse_instruction<std::string>(std::string, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, LinkedList<std::string>*) (main.cpp:101)
==14052==    by 0x402371: main (main.cpp:64)
==14052== 
==14052== 15,528 (16 direct, 15,512 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 18 of 18
==14052==    at 0x4C29203: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==14052==    by 0x403DE3: LinkedList<std::string>::insertAfter(std::string, std::string) (LinkedList.h:94)
==14052==    by 0x402DF6: void parse_instruction<std::string>(std::string, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, LinkedList<std::string>*) (main.cpp:111)
==14052==    by 0x402371: main (main.cpp:64)
==14052== 
==14052== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14052==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
==14052==    indirectly lost: 16,161 bytes in 687 blocks
==14052==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14052==    still reachable: 259 bytes in 6 blocks
==14052==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==14052==                         stdstring          : 259 bytes in 6 blocks
==14052==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14052== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==14052== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==14052== 
==14052== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14052== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202411/discussion-on-question-by-user3304179-what-do-i-not-understand-about-memory-leak).

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to encourage you in your training with data structures, I think it is the best way to learn programming, from pointers and memory to divide and conquer algorithms and multi threading applications.

Now, I see that your code does not strictly follow [Stackoverflow Minimum Reproducible Example guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it contains methods that are not related to the leak, as 'at', 'toString' and 'size' and does not give a case that could be used to reproduce your valgrind output. I recommend you to careful follow them because otherwise you can earn downvotes in the future. In my case I will take advantage of that to try helping you more in improving your LinkedList implementation.

The main problem I see is that LinkedList destructor does nothing (only deallocates the memory used by itself, not by its nodes), so if your program ends after having adding one element, say:

```
int main() {    
  auto l = new LinkedList<int>();
  l->insertHead(1);
  // l->remove(1);
  delete l;
}
```

The memory corresponding to 1 node (the head) will be leaked. The implementation I would recommend is:

```
~LinkedList() {
  while (head != NULL) {
    Node *nodeToDelete = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete nodeToDelete;
  }
}
```

This implementation should not give you any leak if you call delete on every LinkedList you create, or if you feel prepared, you could use smart pointers which call delete on your LinkedLists when they get out of scope as if you weren't using pointers. But with them you would also get leaks without a destructor that does not free every LinkedList Node properly. I hope this helps you, below I give you other recommendations in case you want to learn more and are interested in making all your LinkedList methods to work as your profesor would expect them to. Good luck.

---

On the other hand, it seems your size method does not count the head when not null. I would simplify it to be:

```
int size() {
  cout << "In size function" << endl;
  int sizeOfList = 0;
  Node *fakeIterator = head;
  while (fakeIterator != NULL) {
    ++sizeOfList;
    fakeIterator = fakeIterator->next;
  }
  return sizeOfList;
}
```

---

### Smart Pointer Bonus:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {    
  auto l = make_unique<LinkedList<int>>();
  l->insertHead(1);
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==3288== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3288== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3288== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3288== Command: ./run
==3288== 
In insertHead function
==3288== 
==3288== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3288==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3288==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 73,760 bytes allocated
==3288== 
==3288== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3288== 
==3288== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3288== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```